# Is there a way to perform action when HTML5 notification dissappears?

Tags: javascript, html, notifications

According to MDN, the `onclose` event for `Notification` API is obsolete:

> The following event handlers are still supported as listed in the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification#browser_compatibility) section below, but are no longer listed in the current spec. It is safe therefore to assume they are obsolete and may stop working in future browser versions.
>
> - [`Notification.onclose`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/onclose)
>     A handler for the [`close`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) event. It is triggered when the user closes the notification.
> - [`Notification.onshow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/onerror)
>     A handler for the show event. It is triggered when the notification is displayed.

I have script that, under certain circumstances, generates following notification:

> *X has happened. Click here to deal with it, ignore or close this notification to continue running.*

If the user clicks the notification, script is stopped and user can deal with the situation. If the notification is not clicked, the script will continue with it's work after the notification is closed/disappears.

How to do that now that `onclose` event is deprecated?

Comment: I had the same problem but in my case i just use `setTimeout` but i think will not solve all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API#Closing_notifications), you should be sending your own `close` commands because Chrome doesn't do that on its own. It would be trivial to co-opt that to handle the event.

Something like this:

```
let notification = new Notification('Test Notification');

setTimeout(close(notification), 5000);

function close(n) {
    n.close.bind(n);
    // your other code...
}
```